# Log custom web request headers with NLog

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, nlog, request-headers

I'm trying to log request number in my Web Api application adding it as custom request header on the first DelegatingHandler:

```
    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        request.Headers.Add(WebApiConstants.Headers.WebRequestCounterHeader, Interlocked.Increment(ref _requestsCounter).ToString("X8"));

        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
```

Where:

```
public const string WebRequestCounterHeader = "RequestIndex";
```

Part of my NLog configuration presented below:

```
  <variable name="RequestNumber"
            value="${aspnet-request:serverVariable=HEADER_RequestIndex}" />
    <target name="TraceLogger"
            type="File"
            fileName="${TraceFullPath}"
            archiveFileName="${TraceArchiveFullPath}"
            maxArchiveFiles="100"
            archiveNumbering="Sequence"
            archiveEvery="Day"
            layout="${FormattedDate} ${message}${RequestNumber} -> ${HttpMethodPadded} ${Url}" />
```

But my logged messages doesn't contain a request number:

```
26.10.2015 18:11:22.11 Begin -> [POST]    /api/v1/login
```

According to MSDN and NLog help:
HEADER_
Unlike HTTP_, all characters in HEADER_ are interpreted as-is. For example, if you specify HEADER_MY_HEADER, the server searches for a request header named MY_HEADER.

What NLog configuration will be correct in my case?